# What's the exact meaning of "make to a budget"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The sentence is as follows:

***This isn't just an Apple tablet made to a budget***

Am I correct in assuming it means:

*This isn't a cheap tablet made within certain budgetary constraints so that you can buy it for exactly ... dollars?*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's essentially saying ***"this isn't just a cheap version of X"***.